# Polling a Ria Service every minute on a Silverlight application

Tags: silverlight, background-process

just a small clarification I need to call a ria service every minute in the background of my silverlight application.

My idea is to initialize a timer on the App and call the Ria Service on elapsed of the timer. If I use a Threading.Timer I get an exception of invalid thread. What would be the best way to do this?

I also tried the DispatcherTimer, but how does a DispatcherTimer affects the UI? Can it work on the background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use DispatcherTimer. And make sure to create it on UI thread.

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply, I did it with dispatchertimer then after i get the data I use a background worker to process it.